# How can I overwrite existing map instead of adding a new one below (OpenLayers)?

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to build a web map with a number of layers that can be toggled on and off. Initially the map gets drawn without any issues, but when I try to toggle off any layer, a new map is added below the existing one (instead of replacing it).

When I toggle off a layer, a javascript refresh() function is called. This function needs to rebuild the list of layers to draw and then call again the function that builds the map. I was hoping this would just replace the existing, but instead a new map gets added below.

```
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="ol.js"></script>        

<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">

    function onLOAD()
    {
        var my_layers = 'layer_1,     \
                         layer_2,     \
                         layer_3,     \
                         ...'
        init(my_layers);
    }


    function init(my_layers){

        //The bounding box of Lund:lund_address_point
        var extent = [13.1267,55.6770,13.2601,55.7597];

        //Initial view
        var view = new ol.View({
                   center: ol.proj.transform([13.192927, 55.708944], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                   zoom: 13
                   });              

        //The source for the layers
        var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Test/wms',
                        params: {
                                 'LAYERS': my_layers
                                },
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                        });             
                        
        //OpenStreetMap background and my_layers
        var layers = [
                      new ol.layer.Tile({
                          source: new ol.source.OSM()
                          }),
                      new ol.layer.Image({
                         source: wmsSource
                          })
                      ];
        
        //Bind the map object to our "map" div and add some extra functionality
        var map = new ol.Map({
                  layers: layers,
                  controls: ol.control.defaults({
                            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                                 collapsible: false
                          })
                  }).extend([
                        //Extra functionality of the map
                        //Control for displaying coordinates
                        new ol.control.MousePosition({
                             coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                             projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                             className: 'custom-mouse-position',
                             target: document.getElementById('location'),
                             undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
                        }),
                        //Control for displaying a scale line
                        new ol.control.ScaleLine({
                            target: document.getElementById('scale-line')
                        }),
                        //Control for zooming to a defined extent
                        new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
                            extent: ol.proj.transform(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                        })
                  ]),
                  target: 'map',
                  view: view
        });

    }

    
    function refresh(){
      my_layers='';
      if (layer_1.checked) my_layers = my_layers + "layer_1,";
      if (layer_2.checked) my_layers = my_layers + "layer_2,";
      if (layer_3.checked) my_layers = my_layers + "layer_3,";
      ...  
      if (my_layers.length > 1){
        my_layers = my_layers.substring(0,my_layers.length-1);
      }
      init(my_layers);
    }           
    
</script>
</head>     



<body onload="onLOAD()">

<div>
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="layer_1" value="layer_1" checked="checked" onClick="refresh()">Layer_1
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="layer_2" value="layer_2" checked="checked" onClick="refresh()">Layer_2
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="layer_3" value="layer_3" checked="checked" onClick="refresh()">Layer_3
    ...
    ...
</div>

<br>
<div id="map"></div>
<br>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="location"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="scale-line" class="scale-line"></div>
</div>

...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cleanly remove the old map you need to call `map.setTarget(null)` on the previous Map object.

But in your case it might be better to only create a single map and update the layers' visibility.
This way the map / view states like loaded tiles, center and zoom are remembered.

```
<div>
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="input-osm" value="osm" checked="checked">OSM
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="input-image" value="image" checked="checked">Image
</div>
```

Declare the map and layers variables outside the init function so it can be accessed from the refresh function.

```
var map, layers;
```

Store your layers in an object and assign to declared layers variable to be able to reference them by name and initialize them with correct visibility:

```
layers = {
    osm: ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        visible: document.getElementById('input-osm').checked,
    }),
    image: new ol.layer.Image({
        source: wmsSource
        visible: document.getElementById('input-image').checked,
    })
};
```

Assign map with all layers to previously declared variable:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: Object.values(layers),
    ...
```

On user input layers' visibility should be changed according to the checkbox:

```
function refresh(checkbox) {
    layers[checkbox.value].setVisible(checkbox.checked);
}
document.getElementById('input-osm').addEventListener('change', refresh);
document.getElementById('input-image').addEventListener('change', refresh);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Where should I add "map.setTarget(null)" within my code?

Comment: I am confused about your 2nd suggestion. wmsSource is a list a 9 layers in my case. Would it work anyway? And what's the HTML elements with id 'layer-image'?

Comment: I edited my answer, 'layer-image' should be 'input-image', the checkbox input.

Comment: The `map.setTarget(null)` should be called in the first line of your `init` function. But you need to declare the map variable outside that function so you can access the previously created map. And of course the first time it will be undefined, so add a check for when it is undefined.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your code. I have tried it anyway and it doesn't work (it doesn't even draw the layers at the beginning). Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I managed to get it working with "map.setTarget(null)". It's true that your other suggestion would be more elegant (if I managed to get it working). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly! Make some changes to the HTML. `refresh(this)`

```
...
<input type="checkbox" id="layer_1" value="layer_1" checked="checked" onClick="refresh(this)">Layer_1
...
```

javascript

```
var layersMap;
function onLOAD() {
  var my_layers = "layer_1,layer_2,layer_3";
  init(my_layers.split(","));
}

function init(layerNames) {
  //The bounding box of Lund:lund_address_point
  var extent = [13.1267, 55.677, 13.2601, 55.7597];
  //Initial view
  var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([13.192927, 55.708944], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    zoom: 13,
  });
  //Bind the map object to our "map" div and add some extra functionality
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    controls: ol.control
      .defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
          collapsible: false,
        }),
      })
      .extend([
        //Extra functionality of the map
        //Control for displaying coordinates
        new ol.control.MousePosition({
          coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
          projection: "EPSG:4326",
          className: "custom-mouse-position",
          target: document.getElementById("location"),
          undefinedHTML: "&nbsp;",
        }),
        //Control for displaying a scale line
        new ol.control.ScaleLine({
          target: document.getElementById("scale-line"),
        }),
        //Control for zooming to a defined extent
        new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
          extent: ol.proj.transform(extent, "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
        }),
      ]),
    target: "map",
    view: view,
  });

  layerNames.forEach((layerName) => {
    layersMap[layerName] = generateImageWms(layerName);
    map.addLayer(layersMap[layerName]);
  });
}

function generateImageWms(layerName) {
  return new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Test/wms",
    params: {
      LAYERS: layerName,
    },
    serverType: "geoserver",
  });
}

function refresh(target) {
  layersMap[target.id] && layersMap[target.id].setVisible(target.checked);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Only the OMS layer appears in the map. So I guess the bit "layerNames.forEach((layerName) => ......." is not doing its job?

Comment: Did you try? Layer is first created and then added to the map by `map.addLayer(layersMap[layerName])`